# Insert record in parent and child table

Tags: database

I have two tables one is Master table having 3 cloumns

```
master_id as primary key,
master_name varchar(50),
master_cal varchar(50),
```

The other Child table which has two columns

```
child_id as primary key,
child_name varchar(50)
master_id as foreign key
```

I want to insert data on submit button in asp.net. I need a query or a stored procedure
which inserts the data in master table first and then in child table. please help I am not getting how to get the master_id and put it in the child table as foreign key..

Answer (score 0):

SQL dialects often allow the use of the following syntax:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2)
values ('a', 3)
returning col_for_pk into variable_name.
```

You probably need a technique like that, tailored to whatever RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer, assuming that your master_id, and child_id are IDENTITY fields, you can do

```
INSERT INTO master (master_name, master_cal) VALUES ('Master1', 'Master_cal1');
INSERT INTO child (child_name, master_id) 
SELECT 'Child1', SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be8cd/1)**